# List all group folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hints

Hard to describe with words, I'll rather show you the code and explain along. Right now I can tell you that I'm writing app with UNIX-like rights system and I've ran into one problem, I don't know how to solve yet. Below are my models with relations.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :rights

belongs_to :folder

validates :folder_id, presence: true

end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :rights

belongs_to :user
has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy

validates :name, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id
has_many :folders

has_many :group_users
has_many :groups, :through => :group_users

end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :owner

has_many :group_users
has_many :users, :through => :group_users, dependent: :destroy

end

class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :group_id, :user_id

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :group

end
```

With my system in mind, every user in group should have access to all folders that the group owner owns(not taking rights in account right now). And this is how I tried to list all folders, user has access to.

In Folders controller

```
def list_folders

@user_groups = current_user.groups

end
```

In list_folder view

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<td>Folder name</td>
<td>Documents</td>
<td>Actions</td>
</tr>
<% for group in @user_groups %>

<% user = User.find(group.owner)%>
<% folders = user.folders %>
<% for folder in folders %>
<tr>
<td><%= folder.name %></td>
<td>#</td>
<td><%= link_to 'view', folder_path(folder.id) %></td>
<tr>
<% end%>
<% end %>
</table>
```

So the problem is with the code right now, if user himself owns a group, his folders get fetched aswell. And I don't want this to happen, because I have other place to watch and edit folders that user owns. Here I want to bring only those that he gets from other groups. I tried to somehow exclude him from query but didnt succeed. Then I tried to remove him from @user_groups array but it also didn't work out the way I wanted. I am open to any suggestions on this problem and also if possible, I'd like to get some hints on how to rewrite the code in view, because iterator(or cycle?) in iterator looks messy for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a named scope and retrieve via that.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes